# Flex table like layout same header size

Tags: html, sass, flexbox, jsx

I have the following react component jsx:

```
const TableHead = ({currentData}) => (
<div role="table" className="data" tabindex="0">
  <div className="column">
    <div className="head" >Header</div>
    <div className="value">some Value </div>
  </div>
  <div className="column">
    <div className="head" >Header longer </div>
    <div className="value">some Value</div>
  </div>
  <div className="column">
    <div className="head" >Short</div>
    <div className="value">some Value test</div>
  </div>
  <div className="column">
    <div className="head" >Test</div>
    <div className="value">some Value shorter</div>
  </div>
  <div className="column">
    <div className="head" >Test 2</div>
    <div className="value">some Value longer</div>
  </div>
</div>
);
```

and scss:

```
.data {
  display: flex;
  // grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .head,
  .value {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .head {
    padding: .5rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $text-blue;
    background: $text-grey;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    flex-grow: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }

  .value {
    padding: 0 .5rem;
  }
}
```

because my headings (className="head") have different hight depend on its content, i want to give all head elements the same height of its largest element.

Is this possible with this html markup? I dont want to change the markup because i need some accessibility stuff there.